# How to Batch Convert Azure Pipelines YAML to Github Actions YAML?

Tags: azure-devops, devops, github-actions, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have Azure YAML pipelines that have been created long back and I am now looking into migrating my existing devops solutions form Azure to Github Actions.

How do I approach migrating / translating existing pipelines from Azure DevOps to Github Actions?

Manually translating each ADO Pipeline is not something that would be consider a feasible solution for the number of pipelines I have.

Reference Links:

1. Azure DevOps Pipelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/?view=azure-pipelines
2. Github Actions: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions

Simply put: I need to convert my existing ADO pipelines to Github Actions

I am thinking of building a tool to serve this purpose of converting Azure DevOps pipelines to Github Actions but need ideas on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Are you moving a way from Azure DevOps totally to GitHub

Comment: Yes, I am, in complete sense. In the process of migration from ADO to GitHub Actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Leo Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7460777/leo-liu)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72107412/6309), May 2022:

> I am afraid there is no such out of box extension or tool to batch Convert Azure Pipelines YAML to Github Actions YAML at this moment.

Update:

> ### [Introducing GitHub Actions Importer](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-11-16-introducing-github-actions-importer) (Nov. 2022)
>
> We’ve launched a public preview of GitHub Actions Importer, which helps you forecast, plan, and automate migrations from your current CI/CD tool to GitHub Actions.
>
> Doing individual migrations is relatively easy in isolation.
> However, for those that have a large and established CI/CD footprint, having tooling available to assist with migrations is key to their ability to adopt Actions at scale.
>
> In the time that we’ve been developing and using GitHub Actions Importer in its private preview form, we’ve encountered numerous customers that have thousands of pipelines—even in excess of 15K—in their legacy environments that need to be migrated.
>
> GitHub Actions Importer is designed to help when manual migration is not feasible, such as when users have a large number of teams that depend on hundreds or thousands of workflows.
>
> To learn more, see [Automating migrations with GitHub Actions Importer](https://docs.github.com/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/automating-migration-with-github-actions-importer) and the [announcement post](https://github.blog/2022-11-10-introducing-github-actions-importer/) on the GitHub blog.
>
> Sign up [here](https://github.com/features/actions-importer/signup) to request access to the public preview.

So check it out: it does list Azure DevOps in its [Supported CI platforms](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/automating-migration-with-github-actions-importer#supported-ci-platforms).

Answer (score 1):

> How to Batch Convert Azure Pipelines YAML to Github Actions YAML?

I am afraid there is no such out of box extension or tool to batch Convert Azure Pipelines YAML to Github Actions YAML at this moment.

There is a tool to make migrations between Azure Pipelines YAML and GitHub Actions YAML easier for one YAML file at a time:

[Convert Azure Pipelines YAML to GitHub Actions YAML](https://github.com/samsmithnz/AzurePipelinesToGitHubActionsConverter)

But the tool for batch convert doesn't seem to exist yet.

Comment: Got it, thanks for mentioning the tool. Any suggestions on how could one go about it if I decide to build one such tool myself?

Comment: @aryashah2k, Since the source code of this tool is open source, you can try to remove the UI display interface based on the source code and replace it with a way of processing yml files in a loop. Of course this is only theoretical, in practice it is up to you to implement it, good luck

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the implementation idea!